# Is there an automated way to generate a typeface specimen using (Xe)TeX?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am looking for some automated way (perhaps using some package) to generate a typeface specimen (examples [here](http://www.designer-daily.com/8-inspiring-type-specimens-1392)) using LaTeX. I can use either pdflatex or XeLaTeX, whatever you can provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The examples you link to are quite varied, so I'm not completely sure what you want. There are a few packages for producing dummy text (like *lorem ipsum* text): the `lipsum`, `kantlipsum` and `blindtext` packages.  Perhaps these are what you are looking for?

Comment: There is also the `fontsmpl` package, which will work with `pdflatex` only.

Comment: Your references look nice and useful... Still, I am looking also for something that does not rely so heavily on standard document structures, and which could possibly deal with automating text generation in various sizes and weights. But I think `blindtext` and `fontsmpl` can give a nice headstart... Thanks!